# Can my Primal Companion roll initiative instead of my character?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, initiative

In Tasha's Primal Companion feature it doesn't say that the beast doesn't roll initiative, just that it acts during the player's turn. Is that enough to mean that it's the player that has to roll initiative?

I assume the answer is yes, but it would be nice if you were playing a strength build ranger, or to take advantage of the Primal Bond.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### You roll initiative, not your companion.

Primal Companion says:

> In combat, the beast acts during your turn.

Normally, participants in a combat will roll initiative, but this rule creates an exception:

> Remember this: If a specific rule contradicts a general rule, the specific rule wins.

Instead of following the general rule and having the companion roll initiative, it acts on your turn instead, which is determined by your initiative roll.